# How do I "getActionCommand" from a JTextField? I SEE it when debugging but

Tags: java, jbutton, jtextfield

I wrote a cute Tictactoe game using what little I knew about Java last month. An integral part of it is in the 3 code snippets below:

```
// from the constructor ...
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        guiFrame.add(buttonPanel);//, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            button[i][j] = addButton(buttonPanel, i, j);
// ...

     private JButton addButton (Container parent, int row, int col) {
        int v = (10 * (row + 1) + col + 1); // 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, ... 33
        String s = " " + v;
        JButton cell = new JButton();
        parent.add(cell);
        cell.setActionCommand(s);
        cell.addActionListener(this);
        return cell;
      }  

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// ... snip
        String r = e.getActionCommand().substring(1, 2);  // row 1, 2, or 3
        String c = e.getActionCommand().substring(2, 3);  // col 1, 2, or 3
        try {
          row = Integer.parseInt(r);      col = Integer.parseInt(c);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {            }
       }
```

The gist of it is to store (row,col) info into the each cell's "action command" so I can later use `getActionCommand` to tell whose cell contains X or O (through logic not shown).

Might be better way; whatever, it works.

Now I'm onto dealing with an 11x11 grid that's more or less a crossword puzzle grid. I wanted to use similar logic to determine in which `JTextField` a keypress combo was just struck to determine whether to set background to black. Here's very similar logic for adding cells:

```
 private JTextField addCell (Container parent, int row, int col) {
    JTextField cell;
    cell = new JTextField();
    int v = (100 * (row + 1) + col + 1);
     // v will go 101,102,...111; 201,202,...,211; ... 1101,1102,...1111
    String s = "" + v;
    cell.setActionCommand(s);
    parent.add(cell);
    cell.addKeyListener(this);
    cell.addActionListener(this);
    return cell;
  }
```

But I can't find something like `getActionCommand` for a `JTextField` listener's event.

Here's what I get (greatly edited for readability) from the `System.out.println("keyPressed " + evt.getSource());` statement in  `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)`:

```
keyPressed JTextField  
[
 ,  5,  5,  34x32,
 layout =  BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,
 alignmentX = 0.  0,  alignmentY = 0.  0,
 border =  BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f864fe,
 flags = 296,
 maximumSize = ,  minimumSize = ,  preferredSize = ,
 caretColor = PrintColorUIResource  [r = 51,  g = 51, b = 51],

 disabledTextColor = ColorUIResource  [r = 184, g = 207, b = 229],
 editable = true,
 margin =  InsetsUIResource [top = 0, left = 0, bottom = 0, right = 0],

 selectedTextColor = PrintColorUIResource  [r = 51, g = 51, b = 51],
 selectionColor = ColorUIResource  [r = 184, g = 207, b = 229],
 columns = 0,  columnWidth = 0,  

                                   command = 101,

 horizontalAlignment = LEADING
]
```

And *thar she blows*, next to last line, `command = 101`, just what I need to get at, but "command" is not available anyway I've tried.

Your thoughts/advice/helllllllp?

Comment: Nope, once set, you can't get it back :P - You could use an `Action` instead, which the text field allows you to list back or you could use `set/getClientProperty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to rewrite this program since it got out of hand and was truly trash--a large mass of "tortured code".

When I got to the same basic area as above--"How do I know which grid cell invoked the keyListener when the mouse is clicked or a key is pressed in a cell?", I NOW use `e.getComponent().getLocation()`, which gives pixel addresses relative to (0,0), which is the upper left corner of the frame containing the grid.

I then use a linear function `interp` to determine row and column of `grid[][]`:

```
 private static int interp(int z){
   return (z - 5)*10/400;
 }
```

This works nicely because my 11x11 grid is 440x440 pixels.

This code in both `keyPressed` and `mouseClicked`  does the trick:

```
xpix = e.getComponent().getLocation().x;
ypix = e.getComponent().getLocation().y;
setCursor(interp(ypix), interp(xpix));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which component generated the event you should be using the event to get the source:

```
e.getSource();
```

The action command is only for the ActionListener (in which case you would use the getActionCommand() method of the ActionEvent) and not a KeyListener.

Edit:

Create a Map to hold the information you need:

```
Map<Component, Point> textFields = new Hashmap<Component, Point>();
```

Now in the addCell method you add the data to the map:

```
textFields.put(cell, new Point(row, col));
```

Then in the KeyListener you access the Point:

```
Point whatever = textFields.get(event.getComponent());
```

Now you know the row/column of the text field where the text was entered.

Or, as MadProgrammer has already suggested you can add your Point as a client property of each JTextfield. That approach is probably a little easier than this suggeston. However, that approach will create a Map for each JTextField and this approach only creates a single Map for all text fields so it is more efficient.

Comment: I'm fulla ... stuff. The whole thing about 'id' is bogus. The value (401) LOOKS like one of "my" values, but it's not. Every keypress generates 401.

Back to square (1,1).

After I edit the 'id' stuff OUT of my original post.

Comment: println output of e.getSource() shows a "thing" named "command", which contains the data I need. But how do I get to it? e.getComponent() also has "command", and it has a TON of methods that can be called, NONE of which contains what "command" does: "101" or "305" or "1111" or whichever cell was active when the cursor key was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

SURELY there's a better way than THIS:
THERE IS--SEE ANSWER PRECEDING THIS

```
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) { 
    String s = (evt.getComponent().toString());
    StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer("0");
    int start = s.indexOf("command") + 8;
    int thru = s.indexOf(',',start);
    cmd.append(s.substring(start,thru));
    if(cmd.length() > 4) 
         s = cmd.substring(1);
    else s = cmd.toString();
    int row = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2));
    int col = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2,4));
}
```

But if not, I got what I wanted.... ugly, though, and tortured as far as logic goes--tortured by fatigue and frustration.

*(Hey--I just discovered the "draft saved" feature--StackOverflow ROCKS!!)*

Comment: Please note that it's the next-to-last "Answer" that contains the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better/different way:

```
  public Cell commandToCell(String s){
    Cell c = new Cell();
    int start = s.indexOf("command") + 8;
    String s1 = s.substring(start,start+1);
    String s2 = s.substring(start+1,start+2);
    if(s1.charAt(0) == 'A') c.row = 10; else c.row = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    if(s2.charAt(0) == 'A') c.col = 10; else c.col = Integer.parseInt(s2);
    return c;
  }
```

which I call from `keyPressed` via

`Cell cursorCell = commandToCell(evt.getComponent().toString());`

Note that `getSource()` doesn't tell me which cell of the 11x11 grid is being dealt with, which is why I'm using setActionCommand.